# error building static HTML pages in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby, netlify-cms

Getting an error when building  site even though Gatsby develop works fine, the markdown is coming from Netlify CMS. The specific error is:

```
error Building static HTML failed for path "/null"

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.app/debug-html

  11 | export default function Template({ data }) {
  12 |   const { markdownRemark } = data;
> 13 |   const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark;
     |           ^
  14 |   return (
  15 |     <Layout>
  16 |       <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />


  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'frontmatter' of null

  - blogTemplate.js:13 Template
    lib/src/templates/blogTemplate.js:13:11
```

I have been reading the other similar paths and have tried changing the path in my markdown files from the cms but it was to no avail.

### gatsby-config.js

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
        name: "markdown-pages"
      }
    },
```

### blogTemplate.js

```
export default function Template({ data }) {
  const { markdownRemark } = data; 
  const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />
      <div className="blog-posts">
        <h1 className="blog-title">{frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <h2 className="blog-date">{frontmatter.date}</h2>
        <div
          className="blog-post-content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
        />
        <Link to="/blog/" className="backBTN">
          Go Back
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        path
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

### gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require("path");

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blogTemplate.js`);

  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }

    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: `${node.frontmatter.path}`,
        component: blogPostTemplate,
        context: {}
      });
    });
  });
};
```

### GraphQL

the query returns the following error unless I pass in a specific path of one of the blog posts then it returns the correct results

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$path\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[graphql screenshot with variable passed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCxf2.jpg)

I think that is all the relevant code that is needed here, just let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Is the same query working in the graphiQL?

Comment: Will edit my original post to make it easier with screenshots, but in short no, I am getting `"message": "Variable \"$path\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",`, but if I set the variable of $path to the path of one of your blogs, the query returns the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this very first line of the error:

> error Building static HTML failed for path "/null"

I bet one of your `.md` has an empty path. Maybe you can try filtering to find a markdown node with empty frontmatter path, or null?

If that path was coming directly from netlifyCMS & you use the `string` widget, IIRC you can pass in a `default` options so it'll fallback to that

Comment: Hey thanks for this, you were right there was an empty path. Thank you